# Accessibility identifier is not working for SwiftUI ToolbarItem in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swiftui, appium, accessibility, ios14.5

I'm setting the `accessibilityIdentifier` for `ToolbarItem` in `NavigationView`, which is working fine in iOS 15.0 and above, but they are not shown up in iOS 14.x. I'm using [Appium](https://appium.io) for testing `accessibilityIdentifier`s. I have attached the screenshot of Appium and code. Can you please look into it and help me to figure out.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try older `accessibility(identifier: ..)`

Comment: Hey @Asperi, thanks for your response. But it didn't solve the issue.